# 8086 assembly mov instruction not error

Tags: assembly, x86-16, mov

Im write this code in 8086 emulator and emulate but not give any error why?

```
org 100h

mov 1ah,dh

ret
```

edit:
this is the emulate output
[image]

Comment: Does it show the associated machine code?

Comment: What is your assembler ?

Comment: emu8086 version 4.08

Comment: yes show the machine code.

Comment: Post it then, might give some clue as to what's going on there

Comment: Interesting. I can sort of see how that bug might happen, that doesn't mean that's the reason but.. in the part of their code that decides based on the arguments what kind of `mov` it is, maybe their decision tree just didn't take this into account and it ended up in the "r/m, reg" branch just because it fell out of all other branches. Pure conjecture of course. Something like that also happened when I wrote an assembler too, so it's not a completely random idea.

Comment: MASM uses `ds:1Ah`, so EMU8086 is not the only assembler using a syntax like this. But contrary to EMU8086, MASM requires `ds:` in displacement-only addressing-mode, and `ds:` is not a segment override in this one. If I remember correctly, A86 also uses `ds:1Ah`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emu8086` changed `mov 1ah,dh` to `mov [1ah],dh`. With square brackets it means: store `DH` to the memory at address `DS:001A` (**not 0001A**). I'd like to say that this behavior is a bug.